# Issue when trying to insert an XML sub-tree as new element using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

(This is the XML variant of [JSONizing nested Perl objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68980080/6607497))

Creating an XML presentation of my object, I deferred creating XML for the sub-objects to those.
After an initial version was working, but created an unnecessarily deeply nested structure, I tried to flatten the structure somewhat, but ran into a problem I was able to solve via some ugly work-around only.

Let's view this code snippet (executed in a `foreach` loop):

```perl
my $child = XML::Twig::Elt->new('sample', { 'name' => $_ });
my $F = $val->{$_}->XML_string($child);
$F->print;
$child = $elt->insert_new_elt(last_child => 'dummy');
$child->replace_with($F);
```

`$F` (assigned to a temporary variable for debugging purposes) contains the XML sub-tree for the object `$val->{$_}`
(`$val` is the current object slot being processed, and in this case it's a collection (hash) of sub-objects.
So `$val->{$_}` is the sub-object to process).
The sub-tree is added as children of the extra parameter (`$child`, i.e.: `sample`).

What I wanted to do was `$elt->insert_new_elt(last_child => $F);`, but that never worked.
So I insert a `dummy` element at the right position, just to replace it afterwards.

Here is some debugging output for these lines:

```perl
### The parent node where the new 'sample' children should be added
  DB<4> p $elt->print
<perf_data/>
### The new child (it's still too complex...)
  DB<5> p $F->print
<sample name="max"><label>max</label><value>2.48584</value><unit/><warn><range part="end">0.5</range><range part="inverted">0</range><range part="start">0</range></warn><crit><range part="end">1</range><range part="inverted">0</range><range part="start">0</range></crit><min>0</min><max/></sample>
### the dummy child
  DB<6> p $child->print
<dummy/>
### The parent after adding the dummy child
  DB<7> p $elt->print
<perf_data><dummy/></perf_data>
### the parent after having replaced the dummy child with the real one
  DB<8> p $elt->print
<perf_data><sample name="max"><label>max</label><value>2.48584</value><unit/><warn><range part="end">0.5</range><range part="inverted">0</range><range part="start">0</range></warn><crit><range part="end">1</range><range part="inverted">0</range><range part="start">0</range></crit><min>0</min><max/></sample></perf_data>
### more 'sample' elements to follow...
```

How can I avoid the temporary `dummy` element?
I tried to find pout from the docs, but failed.
Maybe to add the children in-order, I should use something other than `insert_new_elt` (maybe an `append_new_elt`?), but most of the docs is about parsing existing XML, not constructing XML.

### Simplified alternate version

As I was asked to provide a simplified version, here is one.
However it's only a little bit similar to the original data structures.
At least I tried to preserve the essence of the problem.

So here is the code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.018;

package FOO;

use constant ATTRIBUTES => (
    ['a', 0],
    ['b', 1],
    ['c', 2],
    ['d', 3],
);

sub new($)
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = [];

    $#$self = 4;
    bless $self, $class;
    foreach (@$self) {
        $_ = int(rand(10))
    }
    return $self;
}

use XML::Twig;
sub XML_string($;$)
{
    my ($self, $root) = @_;

    $root //= XML::Twig::Elt->new(__PACKAGE__);
    foreach (ATTRIBUTES) {
        my ($name, $i) = @$_[0, 1];

        if (defined(my $val = $self->[$i])) {
            my $elt = $root->insert_new_elt(last_child => $name);

            if ($i == 1 || $i == 2) {
                my $range = $elt->insert_new_elt(last_child => 'range');

                $range->set_att('baz' => $val);
            }
        }       # else leave out
    }
    return $root;
}

package BAR;

use constant ATTRIBUTES => (
    ['e', 0],
    ['f', 1],
    ['g', 2],
    ['h', 3],
);

sub new($)
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = [];

    $#$self = 4;
    bless $self, $class;
    foreach (@$self) {
        $_ = int(rand(10))
    }
    return $self;
}

use XML::Twig;
sub XML_string($;$)
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $xml = XML::Twig->new()->set_xml_version('1.0')->set_encoding('utf-8');
    my $b = XML::Twig::Elt->new(__PACKAGE__, {'version' => '1.0'});

    $xml->set_root($b);
    foreach (ATTRIBUTES) {
        my ($name, $i) = @$_[0, 1];

        if (defined(my $val = $self->[$i])) {
            my $elt = $b->insert_new_elt(last_child => $name);

            if ($i == 1) {
                my $e = $elt->insert_new_elt(last_child => 'sample');
                my $F = $val->XML_string($e);

                #print $F->print,"\n";;
                $e = $elt->insert_new_elt(last_child => 'dummy');
                $e->replace_with($F);
            }
        }       # else leave out
    }
    if ($#_ >= 0 && $_[0]) {
        $xml->set_pretty_print('indented');
    }
    return $xml->sprint();
}

package main;
my $f1 = FOO->new();
my $f2 = FOO->new();
my $b = BAR->new();
$b->[1] = $f1;
$b->[2] = $f2;
print $b->XML_string(1), "\n";
```

And a sample output might look like this:

```perl
  DB<3> x $b
0  BAR=ARRAY(0x1b83860)
   0  1
   1  FOO=ARRAY(0xe2ad40)
      0  2
      1  4
      2  0
      3  4
      4  7
   2  FOO=ARRAY(0x1633788)
      0  3
      1  8
      2  0
      3  1
      4  0
   3  3
   4  1
  DB<4> n
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BAR version="1.0">
  <e/>
  <f>
    <sample>
      <a/>
      <b>
        <range baz="4"/>
      </b>
      <c>
        <range baz="0"/>
      </c>
      <d/>
    </sample>
  </f>
  <g/>
  <h/>
</BAR>
```

I hope it's similar enough to the original problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the constructor for the new element. Use the constructor parameters directly for `insert_new_elt`:

```perl
my $child = $elt->insert_new_elt(last_child => 'sample', {name => $_});
$val->{$_}->XML_string($child);
```

or, use `paste`:

```perl
my $child = XML::Twig::Elt->new('sample', {name => $_});
$child->paste(last_child => $elt);
```

Comment: Your answer left out the actual data, and here's a tricky part: I passed the "root" (`$child`) to `XML_string` to let it add the children, then I inserted that root. When using your pattern (without constructing a temporary root), how can I return "unparented multiple children", i.e.: a list of elements? Or should I return a dummy root, and just extract its children from there to add them? Maybe improve your answer.

Comment: Your code sample isn't runnable as is, so I had to simplify it. What is `$val`? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `$val` is a collection of sub-objects, a "hash ref", so `$val->{$_}` is one sub-object, and `XML_string($child)` returns the XML representation added as children of "root" `$child`. See updated question, too.

Comment: A minimal example would be somewhat hard to derive without extensive work. I'll try to add any missing info, however.

Comment: No one else is going to do the extensive work than you :-)

Comment: Well, the bad thing about `XML::Twig` objects is their complex structure, and it seems the only compact way to present them is via `print` or `sprint` methods (as I did). Otherwise I would have added the real `$F`.

Comment: If I comment out the two lines starting with `$e` after `#print`, I'm getting the same output.

Comment: Maybe part of my confusion was to find out how the `$position` parameter actually works. The documentation is not that good on that.

Comment: Once `$child` was inserted at the correct location, adding the sub-elements just worked as it should.